# Implementing an "omnibar" like Google Chrome's... need method to determine query or URL

Tags: javascript, language-agnostic

Before I do this myself I thought I'd ask here and see if there are any quick solutions.

I don't need the history-lookup, autocomplete, or other fancy features of Chrome's omnibar; I just need to detect if a string *looks* like a valid URL (with valid TLDs and scheme/protocol) or ip-address (IPV4 and IPV6).

I'm not sure how to search chrome's code repository for a look at how they do it. So if you can find that for me that would be an acceptable answer (bonus points if you port it to javascript!).

*Tagged as language-agnostic because I don't care what language it is in [well, please no [Ook](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/ook.html) or [LOLCODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOLCODE)]). Javascript will be the final implementation, though.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a regex provided in [RFC2396 - Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) (see appendix B) :

> The following line is the regular
>   expression for breaking-down a URI
>   reference into its components.
>
> ```
>   ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
>    12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9
> ```
>
> The numbers in the second line
>   above are only to assist readability; 
>   they indicate the reference points for
>   each subexpression (i.e., each
>   paired parenthesis).  We refer to the
>   value matched for subexpression    
>   as $.  For example, matching the
>   above expression to
>
> ```
>   http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/uri/#Related
> ```
>
> results in the following
>   subexpression matches:
>
> ```
>   $1 = http:
>   $2 = http
>   $3 = //www.ics.uci.edu
>   $4 = www.ics.uci.edu
>   $5 = /pub/ietf/uri/
>   $6 = <undefined>
>   $7 = <undefined>
>   $8 = #Related
>   $9 = Related
> ```

I don't see a reason to not use regex in this case, especially if you're just checking if it's a URI or if it's a search.

Comment: cool. The only think I'll need to add is a check for a valid protocol in $2 and valid tlds in $4. Now to port to JS.

Comment: "Port" reminds me, do some unit tests that make sure it works for URLs such as `http://example.com:9000/page.php`

Comment: I'm actually interested in your results with this, if you can get rid of that error on your blog do a quick post on it.